# 3D Delaunay triangulation: find tetrahedron enclosing a query point

Tags: interpolation, computational-geometry, vtk, cgal, delaunay

Suppose I have built a 3D delaunay triangulation out of N points.  Now I have a query point, and I need to find the tetrahedron of the triangulation which encloses the query point.  How to do it in the fastest way possible?  I am aware of general octtree and kdtree methods, but I was hoping that there is a fast method that utilizes the fact that the tetrahedrons are not arbitrary, but rather the result of 3D delaunay.

I can use VTK or CGAL or another C++ library, and the code should be in C++.

Answer (score 1):

This [example](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_3/Triangulation_3_2simple_triangulation_3_8cpp-example.html) shows how to use the [`locate()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_3/classCGAL_1_1Triangulation__3.html#a280891e681597215a86d63399ae7464c) function for the 3D triangulation of CGAL. If you need to speed up the location and not really the construction, you can put the parameter `LP` of [`Delaunay_triangulation_3`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_3/classCGAL_1_1Delaunay__triangulation__3.html) to `CGAL::Fast_location`.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

In the Green & Sibson method for 2D Delaunay, they implement a search for the nearest neighbor by starting from the center of the cloud and following the edges of the triangulation towards the goal. For uniform point distributions, this leads to a cost of √N operations per search.

I believe that this principle can be generalized to tetrahedrizations and would correspond to a cost ³√N. Not as good as log N, but attractive anyway. If the query points are not random but remain localized, starting from the previous point might further reduce the query time.